# Different Y-Axis scales on Kibana split chart

Tags: kibana, kibana-4

I've got a graph I want to split, so I see the graphs in 3 different rows. However, it autoscales all three graphs' y-axis to the minimum and maximum of all of them. This is very problematic, as one of the graphs has a much larger scale, and the others just look like zeros.

I'm using Kibana 4. Is there a way to specify each grpah uses it's own auto-scaling? or explicitly setting the limits of the scale displayed?

Answer (score 3):

I do not believe it is possible to accomplish this with the current feature set of Kibana, though there is currently an enhancement request asking for it.  See https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/2021.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is still not possible. What you can do now (since version 5. is adding a second y-axis that has got its own scale. See
https://github.com/elastic/kibana/pull/9642

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated, unfortunately having different min and max values is not possible with Kibana at least at the time of writing.

A workaround for having wildly different scales on the split charts can be to try using logarithmic scaling on the y axis. They'll still all have the same min and max like this, but if your variation between different split axes is orders of magnitude different, this can make at least some of them more readable.